# In Python 2.7, How to extract and print date, time, and more

Tags: python, python-2.7, logfiles

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Import the datetime 
from datetime import datetime
import re

#Create two datetime object for limit 1 and limit 2 as dt1 and dt2 respectively
dt1 = datetime.strptime("01:00:00","%H:%M:%S").time()

dt2 = datetime.strptime("04:59:59","%H:%M:%S").time()

#Create a compiler for regular expression
init_re = re.compile(r'(INIT)')

time_re = re.compile(r'(\d+:\d+:\d+)')

# read line from test.log file
for line in open("test.log", "r"):

        match = time_re.search(line) #Search time format for each line
        if match:
             matchtime = match.group(1)
             dt_match = datetime.strptime( matchtime,    '%H:%M:%S').time()       
              #Time formmat match
              if dt_match >= dt1 and dt_match <= dt2:
                  match1 = init_re.search(line) #search INIT format
                  if match1:
                      matchinit = match1.group(0)
                      print match.string.strip()
```

Below is a partial part of the log file:

> 2015-12-15 00:51:01,904 INFO restser.py 113 [INIT] [netkv_restser: peek] [req_id: f0aa7ab5-6192-4231-93cd-82a53936a072]  [request: {u'key_space': u'martech_user_index', u'table_name': u'nettopic', u'key': 9569}]

I want output like this:

```
[Date: ] [Time: ] [INIT] [netkv_restser: ] [req_id: ]
```

Example:

```
[Date:2015-12-15 ] [Time:00:51:01,904 ] [INIT] [netkv_restser:peek ] [req_id:f0aa7ab5-6192-4231-93cd-82a53936a072 ]
```

Note: If you are nice enough to edit the code, be kind enough to provide solutions. I don't wanna sound rude but it irks me.

NOTE: I am using Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Why you ask [a single question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975197/how-to-extract-specific-data-from-a-string) multiple times?

Comment: I wanted help and no one provided it. So I rebuilt my code and asked again. Buddy, Help out no.

Comment: Asking it twice won't help you and is not legal based on SO rules. Anyway, I don't wanna sound rude, but I edited your last question and left an answer too.

Comment: I will, but I want answer for this; That question was wrong.

Comment: @EH, Brother, You provided for raw input. I want it to be in script.

Comment: You shouldn't delete a question that received an answer! You must leave comments under the answer if it not what you wanted and make updates/edits for your question instead of asking it again!

Comment: I'm not riding my back dude, I'm just trying to help you receive your answer and trying to make a cleaner SO for other user.

Comment: comments are not a chat. if you want a cleaner SO for other users then please you both delete your comments. meanwhile i'm trying to write an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to parse each log line. It depends on how fixed the structure of your log file is but this works on the input line you provided.

```
template = '[Date:%s] [Time:%s] [%s] [netkv_restser:%s] [req_id:%s]'
details = re.search('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}).*\[(INIT)\].*\[netkv_restser: *(.*?)\].*\[req_id: *(.*?)\]',s).groups()
output = template % details
```

the output is

```
'[Date:2015-12-15] [Time:00:51:01,904] [INIT] [netkv_restser:peek] [req_id:f0aa7ab5-6192-4231-93cd-82a53936a072]'
```

of course you can `compile` the regex and include in the loop over the file lines

```
pattern = re.compile('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}).*\[(INIT)\].*\[netkv_restser: *(.*?)\].*\[req_id: *(.*?)\]')
template = '[Date:%s] [Time:%s] [%s] [netkv_restser:%s] [req_id:%s]'
for line in open("test.log", "r"):
    details = re.search(pattern, line).groups()
    print template % details
```

Comment: I added an example based on your code. the output of the `search` is a tuple. `%s` is a placeholder for a string. You use the format operator `%` to substitute placeholders with a tuple of values

Comment: If you look at the example there's everything you need

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcase1.py", line 32, in <module>
    print template % details
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: File "testcase1.py", line 31, in <module>
    details = re.search(pattern, s).groups()
NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: Plus it's giving re.search shouldn't have groups()!! what does it mean?

Comment: sorry it was another typo. `s` was my string but then i changed it to `line` to match your code.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log_format_re.py", line 26, in <module>
    details = re.search(pattern, line).groups(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Answer (score 0):

I am posting answer, because it is nice!!
Special thanks to Mr.Francesco and Mr.EbraHim.

## !/usr/bin/env python

## Import the datetime

from datetime import datetime
import re

## Create two datetime object for limit 1 and limit 2 as dt1 and dt2 respectively

dt1 = datetime.strptime("00:00:00","%H:%M:%S").time()

dt2 = datetime.strptime("03:59:59","%H:%M:%S").time()

## Create compiler for regular expression

time_re = re.compile(r'(\d+:\d+:\d+)')

pattern = re.compile('(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}).*[(INIT)].*[netkv_restser: *(.*?)].*[req_id: *(.*?)]')

## set the template for output

template = '[Date: %s] [Time: %s] [%s] [netkv_restser: %s] [req_id: %s]'

for line in open("sample.log", "r"):

```
    match = time_re.search(line) #Search time format for each line
    matchtime = match.group(1)
    #Time format match
    dt_match = datetime.strptime(matchtime, '%H:%M:%S').time() 
    if dt_match >= dt1 and dt_match <= dt2: #time limit is set
        #print value
        detail = re.match(pattern, line)
        if detail:
            print template % detail.groups()
```